# User track within websocket application

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, cookies, websocket

I have a websocket application implemented with Java EE on back end (TomCAT) and AngularJS on front end. Now I have to do new feature, that will throttle client messages number. Each user will be permitted to make limited application calls number within some limited time period. This should be done without authentication (login).

As I know the best method to identify not logged in user is cookie, but as user can close and open browser later, the session cookie will not works, so I have to use persisted cookies. To access and manage cookie from java on server I have to use HTTPRequest/HTTPResponse, but even if I have chance to read cookie send with websocket initial request, I will not be able to set it back (i need this to give user some id within cookie), as there will not be any response. So I have 3 options could works:

1. On client, in JavaScript function, before each websocket message,
   HTTPRequest will be send (AJAX). Server will take cookie from request
   and check if it possible to answer further websocket
   messages(throttle). To identify websocket answers for this particular
   client I can use some random key, generated on UI, and will send it
   with both HTTP and WebSocket call.
2. In HTML template put some call to server (Or do this with AJAX?), and use it to preset user id cookie.
3. Generate cookie on UI in JavaScript function with document prefix, and check if throttle needed on UI before websocket message send.

Please help to find effective solution. Not sure options I have are good fit here.

Comment: No one likes to read a wall of text.

Comment: Yes, really. Looks like new line chars not shown. Will update. Thanks.